# PrimeNG dataTable rowspan example

Tags: datatable, primeng

I am using PrimeNG dataTable.  I would like to have some rows span several columns within the content of the table.  There is a great example for doing this within the headers (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatablegroup) but I'm not sure how to do this within the content of the table.  The number of rows will be dynamic (some may have Weather and Rain, others may have Rain, Water Level, and Streamflow).  Can this be done?

[visual for rowspan > 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j7QC.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem. I couldn't really figure out a native solution and so I did this.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="checkout.items" [footerRows]="footerRows">
        <p-column field="main_title" header="Items" styleClass="item-width">

            <template let-col let-mainVO="rowData">

                <tr><h4>{{mainVO[col.field].main_title}}</h4></tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let c of mainVO[col.field].childVO">
                    <td>{{c.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{c.price}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><h4>Discounts:</h4></tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let d of mainVO[col.field].discounts">
                    <td>{{d.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{d.price}}</td>
                </tr>
                </template>
        </p-column>
        <p-column field="quantity" header="Quantity"></p-column>
        <p-column field="price" header="Price"></p-column>
        <p-column field="action" header="Action">
            <template>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
            </template>
        </p-column>

    </p-dataTable>
```

Here is my json:

```
 this.checkout =
        {
            Message: "CheckoutList",

            items: [
                {
                    mainVO:{

                        main_title: "Value Pack Combo",

                        childVO: [
                            {
                                title: "Financial e-Tutorial",
                                price: "$55"
                            },

                            {
                                title: "e-Tutorial",
                                price: "$75"
                            },
                            {
                                title: "Ratios e-Tutorial",
                                price: "$85"
                            },

                            {
                                title: "economics e-Tutorial",
                                price: "$95"
                            }
                        ],
                        discounts: [
                            {
                                title: "Discount price 1",
                                price: "$120"
                            },
                        ]
                    },

                    quantity: "1",

                    price: "300",
                    currency: "CAD"

                },
                {
                    mainVO:{

                        main_title: "Securities Pack Combo",

                        childVO: [
                        {
                            title: "atios e-Tutorial",
                            price: "$55"
                        },

                        {
                            title: "omicsrial",
                            price: "$75"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "e-Tutorial",
                            price: "$85"
                        },

                        {
                            title: "Micro Tutorial",
                            price: "$95"
                        }
                        ],
                        discounts: [
                        {
                            title: "Discount price 1",
                            price: "$120"
                        },
                        ]
                    },

                    quantity: "1",

                    price: "300",
                    currency:"CAD"
                },
            ],

        }
```

Comment: That is fantastic!!  I really need to utilize the template option more!  One question: the templated table portion has a border around it (so there is space within the cell around the table).  I've tried using css border-style: none and padding: 0px and that doesn't seem to do anything.  Did you have this issue?  Thank you again so much for your insight!

Comment: Well, can you elaborate more? I didn't understand your question. Can you attach a pic or something?

Comment: I wish I had taken a screen shot.  It looked like a table within a table (including the outside border).  What I ended up doing was this:<p-column field="meas_count" header="DataType">
  <template let-col let-dat="rowData">
   <span class="table-data">
   <span class="top-line">Weather</span><hr>
   Rain (in)<hr>
   Water Level (ft)<hr>
   Streamflow (cfs)<hr>
   Wind (mph)
   </span>
  </template>
 </p-column> but what you gave me got me started on the right track so THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Cool. You can accept the answer if you are satisfied. :p